# Google App Engine - only support Java, Python and Go frameworks?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/

In this document, "What frameworks does Google App Engine Support?", it only lists the frameworks for Java, Python, and Go.

So does it mean that for php and node.js etc, Google App Engine (standard) does not support any frameworks?

So if I use php, I would have to write "plain php script" without any frameworks. I could use composer, but I would need to upload the full vendors folders, right?

Are there any "built in" objects I could call? (Something like the built in objects in Google Apps Script)

Even for the basic features such as authentication, I would have to write in plain php script?

Thanks!

Comment: Please click through for each of the languages that interests you and you'll find comprehensive documentation that explains what's possible. For the supported languages, you use your preferred web runtime and Google provides APIs for all the expected "companion" services (auth, logging|monitoring, data services, pub/sub etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine supports many frameworks, especially in the newer runtime environments like Node.js, PHP 7.2, and Python 3.7 that have fewer restrictions. We need to update that page that you pointed to and reduce the ambiguity.

You'll generally still need to keep in mind that App Engine is different and even when you can write to temp file storage that the instances can come and go and things like temp files aren't going to be around later. These differences are what makes App Engine powerful and able to scale up and down.

Comment: For php, and node.js frameworks, I would have to use , Google App Engine (flexible), right?  Or there are For php, and node.js frameworks support for Google App Engine (standard)  too? Thanks!

Comment: You should totally be able to use the standard environment as well. PHP 7.2 and Node in particular on standard should be pretty open to about any framework. I've used CakePHP myself on PHP 5.5 in the older runtime.

Flexible should generally be your choice when you know you need larger underlying instances with more memory or CPU. I would try to start with standard until you determine you absolutely cannot use it.